# Satellite spotting

Tags: spacex, artificial-satellite

My normal activity in early morning and evening is to count how many satellites I can spot which is between 5-7.

At 6 am on 22nd November 
I counted 51 all in single file some 3 abreast; it was amazing.

My question is did Space-X relocate the flight path of the satellites due to the unicorn meteor shower?

Comment: slightly related: [What makes some meteor showers continue for days, while the “Unicorn shower” can be shorter than one hour?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/34018/7982)

Answer (score 1):

If SpaceX wanted to "dodge" the shower, they would change the launch window, not  the trajectory.

The Unicorn Meteor Shower is a brief duration shower occurring Nov 21 or22. It is due to the dust trail of an unknown long period comet. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_Monocerotids. It usually has a duration of **less than an hour** but can have a very high rate of 1000/hr.

With regards to relocating the flight path of a Starlink launch to dodge the shower, this would be fruitless since the shower does not have a geographic location.

Commercial satellite operators sometimes take precautions such as rotating satellites so the solar panels are edge-on to the radiant point https://www.washingtonpost.com/wp-srv/national/daily/nov98/18/meteor111898.htm . But the chance of a given satellite being hit is low. The thing about space is there is a lot of it.

If SpaceX wanted to dodge such a short shower, they would chose another launch window time.